# How to access ReactiveSecurityContextHolder in a class extending HikariDataSource?

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux, multi-tenant, hikaricp

I'm migrating a Spring MVC project to Spring Webflux. For several reasons, we've decided to keep using `spring-data-jpa`, even if we have be careful about blocking and such. Our application supports multi-tenancy and the way we do that is by setting a special database variable for a connection before doing requests. The database takes care of the rest.

The class below is used in the `spring.datasource.type` parameter of the application configuration file.

```kotlin
class TenantAwareDataSource : HikariDataSource() {
    override fun getConnection(): Connection = super.getConnection().also {
        it.createStatement().use{
            sql.execute("SET tnt_id = '" + getTenantId() + "'")
            // ^ called with runBlocking because inline function is a suspend fun
        }
    }

    fun suspend getTenantId(): String{
        return Mono.subscriberContext()
            .map { context: Context ->
                context.get<String>("tnt_id")
            }.log().flux().asFlow().toList()[0]
    }
}
```

Our `getTenantId()` function was working based on the `SecurityContext` class, which uses ThreadLocal to keep the values. It was populated via a servlet filter using a JWT from the client. When shifting to Spring Webflux, we altered the filter to a `WebFilter`, and even managed to inject the needed value into the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`, like this:

```kotlin
class MyFilter: WebFilter {
    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        return chain.filter(exchange)
            .subscriberContext{it.put("tnt_id", getTentantFromJWT())}
    }
}
```

In the Controller endpoint, we've managed to get the stored value:

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/rsch-test")
suspend fun reactiveSecurityContextHolderTest(): String? {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().flux().asFlow().toList().toString()
}
```

However, this is not possible in our `TenantAwareDataSource` class, with the program logging:

```
| onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxMapFuseable.MapFuseableSubscriber)
| request(64)
| onNext(empty)
| onComplete()
```

Whereas the same code will give off a different output if placed in the controller:

```
| onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxMapFuseable.MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber)
| request(64)
| onNext(<tenant_id>)
| onComplete()
```

I'm guessing this happens because the reactive context is not propagated to this class. I realise using ThreadLocal is not an option because:

1. There's no guarantee that the Web Filter will run on the same thread as the SQL variable setting.
2. There's no guarantee that only one job will run on one thread at a time. There could be "collisions".

Do you have any ideas regarding this? Perhaps there's some workaround I've missed.
Thank you.

EDIT:

Added the code requested by @Toerktumlare regarding the attempt to retrieve the ReactiveSecurityContext.

Comment: `TenantAwareDataSource class, with the Mono returning empty. I'm guessing this happens because the reactive context is not propagated to this class` where is rhis code then to figure out why it is not propagated?

Comment: I have completed the example. Hopefully, it's easier to understand now.

Comment: you have not disclosed how this is being called. I dont know Kotlin, but you have to make sure that you are in a reactive context when trying to use the current attached context. If you are not in a reactive context, it will be empty. Look at the context examples in the documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_simple_context_examples you have to within a flatMap to be able to access the context